# Add a custom functionality to send and reply email notification from Case Team Members in Salesforce

Tags: apex, workflow, chatter, case

I am trying to implement functionality to send notification to `Secondary Owner` from the `Case` object in Salesforce. I spoke with support and they say that this is not available out of the box.

As an alternative, I can make a `Workflow Rule` to send a notification email to `Case Team Members`. However, via criteria based and for `Case Team` we can use the `Support Settings` and have via `Comment` to receive `Email Notifications`.

Is there a way for the notification below to be sent to the Case Team Member as well in conjunction with the Case Owner?

[image]

Comment: Hi Dave, please take a moment to view the [help] and read [ask]. What exactly is your question?

Comment: I need to know if there is a configuration able to reply from Outlook to Salesforce to a Team Case Members and this mechanism can interact between members from specific Case. There is an idea but it is not that I am look for. https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Bq1XAAS

Comment: Hi anyone knows how to implement this use cases in Salesforce? thanks